# Basic Socket Chat Program Using Multithreading Raises Errors

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am making a basic chat program using socket and multi threading. The program connected and when a message is sent from the client it raises this error on the server side when executed:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jclarke14\Desktop\Server - 2.py", line 25, in check_for_data
    data = c.recv(1024)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I am a beginner and new to multi-threading and socket. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code for the Client:

```
#Check For Incoming Data

def check_for_data():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print "Other: " + data
        print

#Send Data

def send_data():
    while True:
        message = raw_input("You: ")
        print
        s.sendall(message)

#Start Threads 
t = threading.Thread(target=send_data)
t.daemon = True
t.start() #1

t = threading.Thread(target=check_for_data)
t.daemon = True
t.start() #2
```

And Code for Server:

```
c, addr = s.accept()

print "Connection From: " + str(addr)
print

def check_for_data():
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print "Other: " + str(data)
        print

def send_data():
    while True:
        message = raw_input("You: ")
        print
        c.sendall(message)

#Start Threads 
t = threading.Thread(target=send_data)
t.daemon = True
t.start() #1

t = threading.Thread(target=check_for_data)
t.daemon = True
t.start() #2
```

The Full code is available Here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3t3mUQs3K-iLWY3Y3JZX2YzU2c&usp=sharing

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting the thread your code closes the remote socket in both the server and client code. You need to wait for the thread to complete before closing it's socket.

So, for the server remove the last line `c.close()`. You can wait in the main thread for the child thread using `t.join()`. After that you can close the socket.

You could also change your thread code so that it terminates when the remote client closes the socket. And it is better to pass the socket to the thread than it is to have the thread access a global variable:

```
def check_for_data(c):
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print "Other: " + str(data)
        else:
            print "Client closed connection"
            c.close()
            break

t = threading.Thread(target=check_for_data, args=(c,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

t.join()
#c.close()    # if you don't close it in the thread
s.close()    # close the main server socket
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where am i closing the socket?

Comment: @J.Clarke: the last line of your file(s): `c.close()`. This closes the socket that is connected to the client.

Comment: If you are a beginner, why are you trying to write client-server code?

Comment: @MartinJames: why shouldn't the OP do that? How else will he learn to do it? I think that the OP has done well to get as far as they have since they are _only_ a beginner.

Comment: @mhawke Thank you for your suggestions i have already made a working chat application that was server, client based now i am building up and improving my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks that took a while too get my head around it. So does the socket open and then keep running the code until the end. Could i take away the second thread and replace it with a simple check_for_data() ?

Comment: Alright i have solved that but i have another problem, the server only revives data after you send a message to the client and vice versa? I think taking input in **send_data()** is pausing the **check_for_data** thread

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're calling `s.connect()` on a socket that has already been closed. You see how in your client code (found on the link you attached), you are doing `s.connect((host, port))` inside the `while` statement, that is causing the problem with the `s.close` statement you have later in the same code. To fix that you need to move the `s = socket.socket()` command into your `while` statement before the `s.connect((host, port))` statement; that would ensure that the `s.connect((host, port))` statement will not be executed on a closed socket.